# How to make code reusability possible with Transactions present?

Tags: java

In creating an API for running queries on a MySQL database through Java, I created multiple methods enclosed in Hibernate Sessions and Transactions in the following manner:

```java
public void methodA(){
    // Sessions & Transactions
    hbu.createSession();
    hbu.beginTransaction();

    // Code here

    hbu.commitTransaction();
    hbu.closeSession();
}
```

However, I can't seem to call these methods from other similar methods. The error I encounter is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction already active
```

My understanding is that you cannot create Sessions within already created Sessions. I could copy the code of the methods being called and prevent this, however, this obviously leads to a lot of repeating code.
What is the standard way to handle this?

Comment: You could pass a flag indicating if a new session and/or transaction should be used. You might also look into frameworks that provide a lot of the transaction handling for you (e.g. JPA).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about centralizing the transaction handling in one place and pass in everything else as a lambda? So you have all the necessary try-catch/finally stuff at one place only.

```
    void transactional(Runnable r) {
        hbu.createSession();
        try {
            hbu.beginTransaction();
            try {
                r.run();
                hbu.commitTransaction();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                hbu.rollbackTransaction();
                // perhaps re-throw exception here
            }
        } finally {
            hbu.closeSession();
        }
    }

    void doSmthg(){
    }

    void doSmthgElse(){
        doSmthg();
    }

    void useTransactional(){
        transactional(() -> {
            doSmthg();
            doSmthgElse()
        });

        transactional(() -> doSmthg());
    }
```

You could also further split `transactional()` into 2 methods, one for session control the other for transaction control to get nested transactions within single sessions.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to do this.

The first is JTA but you need a container which supports it.

The second is relying on the getCurrentSession() method of the Hibernate SessionFactory.

`getCurrentSession()` will return a *scoped* session (usually one per thread).

Once you have the session you can get the transaction, and you can test if the transaction has already begun, or not. If the there is one transaction going, you skip both begin and end transaction.

The best thing though is not starting the transaction in your methods.

If you now have methodA() and methodB() which start and commit / rollback the transaction, you should move the begin and commit / rollback to the caller of those methods.

In practice, is the caller who knows what is a transaction or not, not the single method implementing some kind of atomic operation.

So the method using the session should not start or end it, the caller should.

In the case of a web-application, you can, for example, begin the transaction at the start of the request, and commit the result at the end of the request.

If any exception happen you should then clean up the session with a rollback.